# Can I open 2 cameras on android phone

Tags: android

Is it possible for me to open both front and back Camera in my android application?
Or I can either open front or back?

Can I have 2 preview surface? one from front, one from back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple cameras open.  Use `Camera.open(int cameraid)`.  It takes an int between `0` and `getNumberOfCameras()`.  That would allow you to open whichever camera you wish, or all of them at once.